# How to check if user is a member of facebook group using Facebook-Api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the following information using Facebook Api:

- Does the user belong to a specific group?
- Has the user posted a certain news on their personal page?

If so, which methods should be used and which permissions will be required? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Does the user belong to a specific group?

Theoretically via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/ - but not sure what permissions that would actually need; docs say, *“Returns an empty data set if the User is not a member of a Group, or has not granted the app any Group-level permissions.”*, but the only permissions left with “group” in their name currently are `groups_access_member_info` and `publish_to_groups` - you’d have to test if either of those work for this purpose.

> Has the user posted a certain news on their personal page?

You can only go through their posts, and then look at the content to see if it matches what you are looking for; there is no way to search for specific keywords, links or anything like that. Requires permission from the user to access their posts of course.

(But if you think of using that to force users to post a certain thing to get access to any content, or reward them in any way for posting something specific, please be aware that that is absolutely not allowed. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5)

Comment: Thank you very much